# CSS vertical flexbox overflow-y doesnt work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've set the page height of my page to 100% through the `html` and `body` elements. It's a mobile app-like page and so I would like it to render on one page (without a main scrollbar). The three parts

```
<nav>
<div id="main">
<footer>
```

are arranged in a flex column, however, inside the `main` there are items longer than can be displayed in the page, and `overflow-y: scroll;` does nothing. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try setting height to 100vw with reset for margin padding properties. If you can share some code it would be more beneficial!

Comment: You need to set the `#main` some height, than `overflow` will do his job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set height to max-height

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#main-wrapper{ 
width: 500px;
max-height: 200px;    /*Adjust Height*/
overflow-y: scroll!important;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
#main {
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-count: 4;
column-count: 4;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
<div id="container">
lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
</div>
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dnxz3z6/)**. Hope this works for you.!

Comment: Why does it work this way? Can you elaborate? And are there any ways, because this is flex, to prevent the div from having a `max-height`?